# Scanned photo not square

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I scanned a photo onto my computer, but there are some slight warping that formed when scanned the image. The photo is not perfectly square, and the photo is slightly curved. Below is a much exaggerated example, where the red box represents my photo, and the blue box represents a perfect rectangle, anchored at the top left and bottom right of the image.

[image]

What transformations / techniques can I use to correct this?

Comment: Was the scanner a flatbed, or a sheet feeder?  If a flatbed, was the lid shut to hold the photo flat?  Rescanning it seems the best answer.

Comment: Scanner was a flatbed. Lid was shut. I had to do it at FedEx because my scanner wasn't large enough. Don't feel like going back. The image above is much exaggerated - I will do my best to fix it, but if not, I can live with the minor warping.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have used [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to perform all sorts of complex distortions of images to straighten, de-skew, etc. Unfortunately, the tool is command-line oriented (it's not a GUI tool), but it provides you a *lot* of control over what you want to do.

Your case is covered in the [Circular and Radial Distortion Methods](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#circular_distorts) of the online user guide.

Comment: Image Magick looks like a nice little utility. Ultimately, I was able to fix it in PaintDotNet with the Grid Warp plugin. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear. I have not heard of PaintDotNet before. I will have to take a look at it.